# How to disable only one field in form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with multiple text fields.

In the form at the top is a question of two radio buttons:

Go direct or go public.

1. Go direct means you have to supply an email address.
2. Go public means the email box is disabled.

> ```
> <input type="radio" name="target" value="public" />
> <label for "public">Open to anyone </label></br>
> <input type="radio" name="target" value="direct"/>  
> <label for="newEmail">Email address of the person:</label>
> <input type="text" name="newEmail" id='newEmail'>
> </br>    
> </br>
> </br>
> <label for="title">Book title:</label>
> <input type="text" name="title" id='title'></br>
> <label for="location">Location:</label>
> <input type="text" name="location" id='location'>
> ```

**No other form fields must be affected**

Comment: Are you using ASP.net

Comment: Nope, this is a PHP setup

Comment: What do you mean should be hidden when the second one is selected?

Comment: not hidden... disabled/greyed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do stuff like this

```
$('input:radio').on('click',function(){
    if(this.checked && this.value == "public") // this.checked is not necessary as checking value already
       $("#newEmail").prop("disabled",true);
    else
        $("#newEmail").prop("disabled",false);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRwg9/1/)

*Side Note:* I would suggest `click` instead `change()` because radio buttons are often toggled in a group, you do not need to add more than one case or conditional logic like you do with checkboxes. though change can also be used

Comment: @Maxcot Welcome friend :)

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger the disabled state of the email input based on which radio button is selected.

```
var $radios = $('input[type="radio"]');
$radios.change(function() {
    $('#newEmail').prop('disabled', $radios.first().is(':checked'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyGL7/)

Comment: It would be great if you wrap it in change event

Comment: @Satpal That's more like it